# Angular 2 reactive form not working with data model

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-forms, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

When using reactive forms in Angular 2 everything works as expected up until I start using a data model. After which data no longer binds to my child input.

This is how I have things setup in my app.component:

I was able to duplicate it here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-podknk

```
import { Component, OnChanges, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, FormBuilder, Validators } from 
'@angular/forms';

import { Parent, ChildGroup } from './test.model';

@Component({
   selector: 'my-app',
   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
   styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnChanges {

@Output() parent: Parent;

public myForm: FormGroup;  

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    ) {
      this.buildForm()
    }

    buildForm() {
        this.myForm = this.fb.group({
          parentInput: '',
          childGroup: this.fb.group(new ChildGroup()),

        });
    }

     ngOnChanges() {
       this.myForm.reset();
        this.myForm.setValue({
        parentInput: this.parent.parentInput,
        childInput: this.parent.childGroup,
      })
  }

    save() {
      console.log(this.myForm.value)
     }
 }
```

Comment: can you post the edit link to your stackblitz example, otherwise it will not be much helpfull.

Comment: When you call `new ChildGroup` you create object with no properties. This should work https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fcwvpe?file=app/test.model.ts

Comment: updated the link for you - thanks

Comment: @yurzui - your solution worked out swimmingly! Thanks alot.